# Angular2 Material : Custom Validation for Angular Material Input

Tags: typescript, error-handling, angular2-forms, angular-material2

In my Angular 2 and material application, I want to check whether username has already taken or not. If it is already taken then it should show the error.

I am following below guide.
https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#error-messages

**Typescript file**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

const existingUserNames = ['rohit', 'mohit', 'ronit'];

@Component({
   selector: 'input-errors-example',
   templateUrl: 'input-errors-example.html',
   styleUrls: ['input-errors-example.css'],
})
export class InputErrorsExample {

    emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
         Validators.required
    ]

    // I want to call below isUserNameTaken function but dont know 
    // how to use it with Validators so that error message will be visible.

    isUserNameTaken() : boolean {
       this.attributeClasses = attributeClasseses;
       this.attributeClasses.find( object => {
           if(object.attributeClass === this.attributeClass) {
               console.log("found " + JSON.stringify(object));
               return true;
           }
       });
       return false;
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <form class="example-form">
   <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <input mdInput placeholder="Email [formControl]="emailFormControl">
    <md-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
      Email is <strong>required</strong>
    </md-error>

  <!-- I want to make something like that - custom validation -->

     <md-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('username-already-taken')">
        Username is already taken. Please try another.
    </md-error>
  <!-- custom validation end -->        

     </md-form-field>
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at this article https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? If so could you share your solution please.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to change your function to receive a component as parameter and return null if everything is ok and an error object if it's not. Then, put it on the component validator's array.

```
// Control declaration
emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
   Validators.required, 
   isUserNameTaken
]

// Correct validator funcion
isUserNameTaken(component: Component): ValidationErrors {
    this.attributeClasses = attributeClasseses;
    this.attributeClasses.find( object => {
        if(object.attributeClass === this.attributeClass) {
            console.log("found " + JSON.stringify(object));
            // found the username
            return {
                username-already-taken: {
                    username: component.value
                }
            };
        }
    });
    // Everything is ok
    return null;
}
```

It's explained in more depth in the link that [Will Howell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4811678/will-howell) put on the comments. It also explains how to do the same for non reactive forms.

[Tutorial](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html#building-a-custom-validator)